# How do I uninstall the .NET framework?

Tags: .net

I'm having a problem running a VS 2005 app on some machines and not others.  I looked up the error message on google and found a post by someone who had the same error and fixed it by uninstalling and reinstalling the .NET framework.  When I try to do that, Windows won't let me because it is in use.

Am I expected to uninstall everything that is using the framework first, then uninstall the framework, then reinstall, etc.?  Does anyone know of an easier way?

Comment: Can you please provide the actual error messages?

Comment: My thinking initially is that there must be an easier solution - uninstalling and reinstalling the framework is a pretty big deal.  Which framework version? 1.1/2.0? Can you post the error message?

Comment: It's .NET framework 2.0 SP1.  I don't remember the error message.  I'll have to make note of it at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out Aaron Stebner's [.NET Framework Cleanup Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx).  Works quite nicely.

Comment: That did work quite nicely and the uninstall and reinstall fixed my problem.  The app runs just fine now.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 wish i'd found Aaron Stebner's blog earlier. if only this stackoverflow question was on first page of google for *uninstall .net framework* instead of microsoft's hopeless kb908077

Answer (score 2):

Boot into safe mode and uninstall the framework from add/remove programs.